# Access a BindingSource from another Thread

Tags: winforms, multithreading, c#-4.0, bindingsource

i have a beautiful method that I use for interacting with controls that accessed from another thread. But now i see that i need to access a BindingSource and remove an entity. This BindingSource is on a DevExpress GridControl -> GridView.

How can i achieve this operation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work the same way you would access controls from another thread.  Is it safe to assume that the BindingSource was created on the same thread as the form it is on?  If so, rely on the form's InvokeRequired property to tell you if you need to call the forms Invoke method to invoke your function that manipulates the BindingSource.

Comment: I was so close:) i just had to look more carefully. Thank you